# Grouping ID while counting specific attribute values

Tags: sql-server, count, group-by, where-clause

I want to count how many occurrences there is of the value 1 in the attribute months for each ID in a table.

Here is what I am working with

```
    ID.         Months
    1000        1
    1000        1
    1000        2
    1001        2
    1002        3
    1003        1
```

This is what I would like to have

```
    ID.         Count(Months=1)
    1000        2
    1003        1
```

Comment: select id,sum(Months) from tab t where t.Months='1' group by id

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [this tourguide](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to ask questions the right way and to learn more how stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count row for just one month, you can use `WHERE` clause for filtering:

```
select id,
    count(*) as cnt
from your_table
where month = 1
group by id;
```

If you want to get counts for multiple months in one row (it's called pivoting), you can use conditional aggregation in most of the databases:

```
select id,
    count(case when month = 1 then 1 end) as cnt_month_1,
    count(case when month = 2 then 1 end) as cnt_month_2,
    count(case when month = 3 then 1 end) as cnt_month_3,
    . . .
from your_table
group by id;
```

Some databases offer `PIVOT` operator for this task. For that, you'll need to specify which database you are using.